# Проблема с рекурсией в VSC

Tags: python, рекурсия

Немного не могу понять почему программма, не выдавая ошибки с проблемой, связанной с глубиной рекурсии просто выходит, ничего не выводя. Написал я код на visual studio code, и получаетается вот такая проблема, но если запустить код в pycharm, то программа выводит результат. С чем может быть это связано.
Вот код:

```
import sys
import functools
sys.setrecursionlimit(11000000)
@functools.lru_cache(None)
def f(n):
    if n>=10000:
        return n
    elif n<10000 and n%3==0:
        return n+f(n/3)
    
    return 2*n +f(n+3)

print(f(46))
```

Вот так выглядит запуск программ в VSC
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего вы запускаете программу в разных версиях Питона. Ставить гигантский лимит на рекурсию бесполезно: программа исчерпывает стек и её останавливает операционная система.

Comment: Если подумать, перед запуском функции можно "прогреть" кеш так, что глубокая рекурсия не понадобится.

Comment: Если подумать, можно переписать функцию без рекурсии. Сперва переписываете на хвостовую рекурсию, затем превращаете в цикл. Или сразу догадываетесь до цикла - интуицию никто не отменял.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но к сожалению задание надо написать без хвостовой рекурсии и понятно без использования цикла. Нельзя никак увеличить максимальный размер стэка?

Comment: Если бы вы догадались какой лимит поменьше установить вместо *11000000*, вы бы решили задачу.

Comment: Идея с прогревом кеша не понравилась? На что спорим, что я вашу текущую программу (без вызова `setrecursionlimit`) заставлю считать правильно?

Comment: ни на что, я уверен, что так возможно

Comment: Тогда уберите `setrecursionlimit` и попробуйте вызывать `f` так чтобы не было переполнения стека. Это не сложно. Подсказка: `f(9046)`.

Comment: А все равно, когда функция переходит в другую ветку, она даеж один шаг не может выполнить и сразву программа крашится https://imgur.com/a/ivzJi34

Comment: Подумайте при каких *n* рекурсия идёт вниз, при каких идёт вверх. Разработайте стратегию вызова  `f` при которой кеш будет заполнен без ошибок.

Comment: Другой подход: придумайте способ заполнения кеша даже с учётом ошибок. Это у вас не задание, а кладезь программистских идей!

Comment: `n/3` -> `n//3`.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Хотите максимальную длину рекурсии на величину доступной памяти - пишите прогу на C#, например. В питоне больше 20000 выставлять без толку, а в каких-то версиях и 2000 максимум дальше крэшится всё-равно сам интерпретатор.

Comment: По командной строке похоже, что запускаете через расширение code runner (но это не точно). Попробуйте его удалить или отключить.

Comment: @CrazyElf, стек в C# четыре мегабайта по умолчанию. Там те же будут проблемы, только позже.

Answer (score 1):

Почему в PyCharm работает а в VSCode нет, сказать не могу. Возможно вызываются разные версии Питона или в различных конфигурациях.

К делу. Лимит в *11000000* рекурсивных вызовов - это чрезмерно много. Интерпретатор Питона запускается с фиксированным размером стека. Чтобы его померить я использую такую программу:

```
import sys


def rec(n):
    if n > 1:
        rec(n - 1)


n = int(input())
sys.setrecursionlimit(n)
rec(n - 10)
```

Потом подбираю число при котором всё рушится:

> ```
> $ echo 14500 | python depth.py
>
> $ echo 14600 | python depth.py
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> ```

У меня предел между *14500* и *14600*. Ставить большие значения смысла нет. У вас пределы могут быть другими, но точно не одиннадцать миллионов. Для кода из вопроса достаточно *14000*. Задача решена.

Прежде чем идти дальше, починим неточность в делении. `n / 3` в Питоне возвращает вещественное число даже если `n` делится на три без остатка. Не большая ошибка, но без неё проще работать. Правим на целочисленное деление - `n // 3`.

Функция `f` кэширована. Кэш можно заполнить, чтобы избежать переполнения стека при вычислении. Например так:

```
import functools


@functools.lru_cache(None)
def f(n):
    if n >= 10000:
        return n
    elif n < 10000 and n % 3 == 0:
        return n + f(n // 3)
    return 2 * n + f(n + 3)


error = True
while error:
    print('populating cache...')
    error = False
    for n in range(1, 10000):
        try:
            f(n)
        except RecursionError:
            error = True

print(f(46))
```

Блок в середине пытается заполнить кэш для значений *[1, 10000)*. Если произошла ошибка, заполнение кэша повторяется c начала. После пятого цикла кэш заполнен:

> ```
> $ python f.py
> populating cache...
> populating cache...
> populating cache...
> populating cache...
> populating cache...
> 33332674
> ```

Это грубое решение, но оно работает почти при любой глубине стека. Чем мельче стек, тем больше будет циклов заполнения.

До сих пор мы не обращали внимания на то как устроена функция `f`. Два наблюдения:

- если *n* не делится на три, то рекурсивный вызов будет для большего значения и это значение снова не будет делиться на три;
- если *n* делится на три, рекурсивный вызов будет для меньшего значения. Важно что это убывание короткое: каждый раз значение делится на три. Любое число меньше *10000* быстро придёт к единице или к другому значению, которое на три не делится.

Отсюда идея: заполнить кэш для всех *n*, которые не делятся на три и заполнить его от больших значений к меньшим:

```
import functools


@functools.lru_cache(None)
def f(n):
    if n >= 10000:
        return n
    elif n < 10000 and n % 3 == 0:
        return n + f(n // 3)
    return 2 * n + f(n + 3)


for n in reversed(range(1, 10000)):
    if n % 3 != 0:
        f(n)

print(f(46))
```

Это работает быстро и без страшного кода с обработкой переполнения стека.

На последок покажу можно переписать функцию без рекурсии. Для Питона это важно: стек мелкий, глубокая рекурсия - зло.

Сперва перепишем рекурсию на хвостовую:

```
def g(n, acc):
    if n >= 10000:
        return acc + n
    elif n < 10000 and n % 3 == 0:
        return g(n // 3, acc + n)
    return g(n + 3, acc + 2 * n)


def f(n):
    return g(n, 0)
```

Потом отрефакторим:

```
def g(n, acc):
    if n >= 10000:
        return acc + n
    if n < 10000 and n % 3 == 0:
        acc += n
        n //= 3
    else:
        acc += 2 * n
        n += 3
    return g(n, acc)


def f(n):
    return g(n, 0)
```

Потом переделаем в цикл:

```
def f(n):
    acc = 0
    while n < 10000:
        if n % 3 == 0:
            acc += n
            n //= 3
        else:
            acc += 2 * n
            n += 3
    return acc + n
```

Comment: Методика с ловлей исключения рекурсии огонь ))

Answer (score 0):

Там разные методы оптимизации в VCS и Pycharm, попробуй этот код

```
import sys
import functools

sys.setrecursionlimit(11000000)

@functools.lru_cache(None)
def f(n):
    if n >= 10000:
        return n
    elif n < 10000 and n % 3 == 0:
        return n + f(n // 3)

    return 2 * n + f(n + 3)

print(f(46))
```